# Retrieve Username:Password Sent by Curl with Spring Boot

Tags: java, rest, curl, spring-boot

I'm writing a web service using Spring Boot that will allow users to request data using REST calls via curl. For now, users will authenticate using the basic authentication that curl provides. From Spring, how do I retrieve the username:password sent by curl.

Example: curl -u user:pass http://localhost:8080/authenticate
I want the user:pass pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out. To get a username:pasword pair sent by curl using basic auth, you use the `@RequestHeader` annotation with `value="Authorization"`. This can be used to collect data from any field in the HTTP header.

Example for basic auth login method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String authorization) { ... }
```

The `authorization` variable holds the base64 encoded credentials. You can also set a default value or flag the header as required.